# How to use Internationalized human_time_diff() function in Chinese?

Tags: functions, theme-development, multi-language, timestamp, codex

Looking at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff

I'm using an English version of Wordpress.

In my theme template, I would like to define custom text of min, hour, day, week, month, year in Chinese using `human_time_diff()` when looping through posts.

According to the instruction in the Codex documentation:

```
<?php
    printf( _x( '%s ago', '%s = human-readable time difference',
    'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ),
    current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
?>
```

I still don't know how to make the implementation to do the swap using the code above. eg.

```
min -> 分鐘
hour -> 小時
dat -> 天
week -> 週
month -> 月
year -> 年
```

`ago` part should be straight forward.

Is there an example that can demonstrate how it works?

Also, do I need to worry about plurals in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full solution that works for me without modifying the Wordpress core is to clone the `human_time_diff()` function and place it inside `functions.php` as a renamed `human_time_diff_chinese()`, then swap all occurrence of  `human_time_diff()` function with this new `human_time_diff_chinese()` function.

```
function human_time_diff_chinese( $from, $to = '' ) {
  if ( empty( $to ) ) {
    $to = time();
  }

  $diff = (int) abs( $to - $from );

  if ( $diff < HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $mins = round( $diff / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $mins <= 1 )
      $mins = 1;
    /* translators: min=minute */
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 分鐘', '%s 分鐘', $mins ), $mins );
  } elseif ( $diff < DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $hours = round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $hours <= 1 )
      $hours = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 小時', '%s 小時', $hours ), $hours );
  } elseif ( $diff < WEEK_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $days = round( $diff / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $days <= 1 )
      $days = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 天', '%s 天', $days ), $days );
  } elseif ( $diff < MONTH_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $weeks = round( $diff / WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $weeks <= 1 )
      $weeks = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 週', '%s 週', $weeks ), $weeks );
  } elseif ( $diff < YEAR_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= MONTH_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $months = round( $diff / MONTH_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $months <= 1 )
      $months = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 個月', '%s 個月', $months ), $months );
  } elseif ( $diff >= YEAR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $years = round( $diff / YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $years <= 1 )
      $years = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s 年', '%s 年', $years ), $years );
  }

  return apply_filters( 'human_time_diff_chinese', $since, $diff, $from, $to );
}
```

Comment: Why? Why aren't you translating the strings as I described? The real answer is a MO/PO file with the `%s min` etc. strings translated!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I thought you were asking me to translate the strings by direct modification of the `formatting.php` file.  The solution I'm using is straight forward and simple for me to implement.  I'm not familiar with working on MO/PO files nor seeing any MO/PO in my Wordpress installation.  Do you have a complete instruction for MO/PO showing as example to translate `%s min`?  If it works out, it would be a cleaner solution and I'll accept your answer as a more viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the source of `human_time_diff`:

```
if ( $diff < HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $mins = round( $diff / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $mins <= 1 )
        $mins = 1;
    /* translators: min=minute */
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s min', '%s mins', $mins ), $mins );
} elseif ( $diff < DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $hours = round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $hours <= 1 )
        $hours = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s hour', '%s hours', $hours ), $hours );
} elseif ( $diff < WEEK_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $days = round( $diff / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $days <= 1 )
        $days = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s day', '%s days', $days ), $days );
} elseif ( $diff < MONTH_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $weeks = round( $diff / WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $weeks <= 1 )
        $weeks = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s week', '%s weeks', $weeks ), $weeks );
} elseif ( $diff < YEAR_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= MONTH_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $months = round( $diff / MONTH_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $months <= 1 )
        $months = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s month', '%s months', $months ), $months );
} elseif ( $diff >= YEAR_IN_SECONDS ) {
    $years = round( $diff / YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
    if ( $years <= 1 )
        $years = 1;
    $since = sprintf( _n( '%s year', '%s years', $years ), $years );
}
```

As you can see, just translate the `%s min`, `%s mins` etc. strings.

Comment: What does `_n` do?  And what does `_x` do in Codex documentation?  I know it's easy to just modify the source of `human_time_diff` function in `formatting.php` but I would like to avoid modifying the Wordpress core so it won't be an issue when it comes to upgrading.  Is there a way to do some filtering/repalcement of the result in `functions.php`?